# Set Swagger API Key in Spring Boot Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, swagger

I'm following [Camel Swagger Java](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/others/swagger-java.html#_adding_security_definitions_in_api_doc) docs to set securityDefinitions in Camel.

```
rest("/user").tag("dude").description("User rest service")
    // setup security definitions
    .securityDefinitions()
        .apiKey("api_key").withHeader("myHeader").end()
    .end()
    .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
```

```
.get("/{id}/{date}").description("Find user by id and date").outType(User.class)
    .security("api_key")
```

As a result, authorization element appear on Swagger UI, but it has no functionality.

The question is, how can I set the API Key in Spring Boot and enable the authorization element to work as it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best, but I came up with a simple solution using if else statement as a gatekeeper and by simply comparing the provided header API KEY value with the original one.

Once I have set securityDefinitions in Camel, like shown in my question, I've got the authorization element on Swagger UI where API KEY can be entered.

Then I'm sending the request with provided API KEY header to the Service class shown below:

```
public class Service{

    public void Result(Exchange exchange) {

        Message camelMessage = exchange.getIn();

        String api_key = String.valueOf(camelMessage.getHeader("myHeader"));
        System.out.println("API KEY: " + api_key);

        if(api_key.equals("original_api_key_value")){
            exchange.getOut().setBody("OK API KEY!");
            exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
            exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 200);
        }else{
            exchange.getOut().setBody("WRONG API KEY!");
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 401);
        }
   
    }

}
```